# Add extra add to cart button to specific products in WooCommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, product

In Woocommerce I would like to add an extra add to cart button with a specific quantity.

The answer *"[additional add to cart button with fixed quantity in woocommerce single product pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48759369/additional-add-to-cart-button-with-fixed-quantity-in-woocommerce-single-product/48759944#48759944)"* doesn't it mostly and I just need to enable that code **for specific products of any product type.**

Is this possible? What does I have to change…

Answer (score 1):

To handle product variations (on variable products) it's much more complicated and requires to add some JavaScript/jQuery code.

I have separate the product settings restrictions, from the main function, in a custom conditional function and you have the choice between 2 ways:

1) You can use product Ids restrictions:

```
// PRODUCT IDs based ::: Conditional function
function enable_additional_add_to_cart_button( $product_id ) {
    // HERE define your Product Ids in the array
    $product_ids = array(37, 40, 53);

    return in_array( $product_ids, $product_id ) ? true : false;
}
```

2) Or you can use product category restrictions:

```
// PRODUCT CATEGORY based ::: Conditional function
function enable_additional_add_to_cart_button( $product_id ) {
    // HERE define your Product Category terms in the array (can be term Ids, names or slugs)
    $terms = array('t-shirts', 'socks', 'glasses');

    return has_term( $terms, 'product_cat', $product_id ) ? true : false;
}
```

---

Now below is **the main function** that will display an additional add to cart button and that works with one of the conditional functions above.

```
// Additional add to cart button with fixed bulk quantity
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'additional_add_to_cart_button', 20 );
function additional_add_to_cart_button() {
    global $product;

    if( ! enable_additional_add_to_cart_button( $product->get_id() ) ) return;

    $qty     = 12;
    $href    = '?add-to-cart=' . esc_attr( $product->get_id() ) . '&quantity='.$qty;
    $class   = 'single_add_to_cart_button-12 button alt';
    $style   = 'display: inline-block; margin-top: 12px;';
    $btn_txt = __( "Add a case of 12", "woocommerce" );

    ## ---------------------- For non variable products ----------------------- ##

    if( ! $product->is_type('variable') ) :

    // Output
    echo '<br><a href"'.$href.'"= rel="no-follow" class="'.$class.'" style="'.$style.'">'.$btn_txt.'</a>';

    ## ---------- For variable products (handling product variations) --------- ##

    else :

    // Output
    echo '<br><a rel="no-follow" class="'.$class.'" style="'.$style.'">'.$btn_txt.'</a>';

    $data = array();

    // Loop through available variations data
    foreach( $product->get_available_variations() as $variation_data ){
        if( $variation_data['is_in_stock'] && $variation_data['is_purchasable'] ) {
            $variation_id   = $variation_data['variation_id'];
            $attributes_str = '';

            // Loop through variation attributes
            foreach ( $variation_data['attributes'] as $attribute_taxonomy => $term_slug ) {
                $attributes_str .= '&'.$attribute_taxonomy.'='.$term_slug;
            }
            // Set product attributes pairs for variations
            $data[$variation_id] = $href . '&variation_id=' . $variation_id . $attributes_str;
        }
    }
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        var a = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>,  b = '.single_add_to_cart_button-12',
            c = 'wc-variation-selection-needed',    d = 'disabled',
            f = 'form.variations_form',             h = $(c).attr('href'),
            s = '.variations select',               i = 'input.variation_id';

        // On show and hide variation event
        $(f).on('show_variation', function() {
            var found = false;

            $.each(a, function(j,k){
                if( $(i).val() == j ) {
                    found = true;
                    if( $(b).hasClass(c) && $(b).hasClass(d) )
                        $(b).removeClass(c).removeClass(d).attr('href',k);
                }
            });
            if( ! found && ! ( $(b).hasClass(c) && $(b).hasClass(d) ) )
                $(b).addClass(c).addClass(d).removeAttr("href");

        }).on('hide_variation', function() {
            if( ! ( $(b).hasClass(c) && $(b).hasClass(d) ) )
                $(b).addClass(c).addClass(d).removeAttr("href");
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: I'm facing a similar dilemma, I only need to add 10 products with a different button than the usual WooCommerce button, but it only adds one product. Is it possible to do this without javascript? My query showed me this debate

Comment: Thank you. Initially you made a mistake in the code, `(!)`, so I tried to find out if there were any more mistakes in the code, and tell you about it. But my speed at understanding a piece of `php` code cannot match that of someone who knows what it says just by looking at it. As I said in 2 comments, I did some testing and of course I would accept your question, I can even put a reward on an answer obtained. But you quickly deleted the answer, that's your right. I'm only sorry if at any time it offends or bothers you.

Comment: The answer is back in your question… Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77228702/how-to-add-10-units-of-a-product-with-a-new-button-in-the-woocommerce-catalog/77229052#77229052

Answer (score 0):

You can check the product id using [WC_prroduct->get_id()](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Data.html#_get_id)  function

// Only for the product with id 16
    if( $product->get_id() != 16 ) return;

```
$href = '?add-to-cart=' . esc_attr( $product->get_id() ) . '&quantity=12';
$class = 'ingle_add_to_cart_button-12 button alt';
$style = 'display: inline-block; margin-top: 12px;';
$button_text = __( "Add a case of 12", "woocommerce" );

// Output
echo '<br><a rel="no-follow" href="'.$href.'" class="'.$class.'" style="'.$style.'">'.$button_text.'</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for all the clarifications.
I will only have single product types, but I will have some products where I need an add to cart for 6 bottles and for some others, 12 bottles and for some.
I want thinking if I could have an option in the product page, e.g. like a custom field, e.g. wine-box, where I could fill in a 6 or a 12 and this can be displayed as an extra add to cart button (Add a case of 6 text or Add a case of 12 text).
Thanks

Comment: I am attaching a website example
https://www.houseofwine.gr/how/wine/red-wine.html?manufacturer=1390&p=1