# How to add 10 units of a product with a new button in the WooCommerce catalog?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart

I need to add 10 units of certain products to the cart.
For this we have created a new button added to the default WooCommerce button, which is only displayed on certain products.

The drawback is that when we press the button, the 10 units of this product are added, but it does not redirect to the cart, which we do not want to happen.
After adding the 10 units, the user must continue in the store.

I have searched for a solution to the problem and they have offered me a javascript function, but for some reason it does not work. The javascript is supposed to prevent me from being redirected to the cart, but it blocks the button and does not act.

**javascript code**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Maneja el clic en el botón "Añadir 10 al carrito"
    $('.add-to-cart-10').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var productId = $(this).data('product-id');
        var quantity = 10;

        // Agrega el producto al carrito utilizando AJAX
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: wc_add_to_cart_params.ajax_url,
            data: {
                action: 'add_to_cart',
                product_id: productId,
                quantity: quantity,
            },
            success: function(response) {
                // Realiza cualquier acción adicional aquí (como mostrar un mensaje de éxito)
                console.log('Producto agregado al carrito: ' + productId);
            },
        });
    });
});
```

Would it be possible to follow this in another way and without using javascript?
I really don't care how to do it, and after several days working on it, I just want to do it however I can.

I don't understand if there will be a problem, or what happens, I have tried other examples and tested with other code, which adds the button to the product page, instead of the catalog, and it doesn't work either.

I don't know how to find a way to do it, can you give me some idea or example of where to look for information?

```
// Add an "Add 10 to Cart" button on the catalog page for specific products
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'agregar_boton_anadir_10_al_carrito', 10);

function agregar_boton_anadir_10_al_carrito() {
    global $product;

    /// Define an array with the IDs of the products to which you want to apply this functionality
    $productos_especificos = array(3092, 422);

    // Get the ID of the current product
    $producto_id = $product->get_id();

    // Check if the current product is in the list of specific products
    if (in_array($producto_id, $productos_especificos)) {
        echo '<div class="add-10-to-cart-button">';
        echo '<a href="' . esc_url(wc_get_cart_url()) . '?add-to-cart=' . esc_attr($producto_id) . '&quantity=10" class="button">Añadir 10 al carrito</a>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: _"but it blocks the button and does not act."_ - how did you actually verify that? This tries to send the request to update the cart quantity in the background, and currently all the "feedback" you will get, is the statement logged to the console. Did you look for that, and it did _not_ appear? If you want to give the website user appropriate feedback they will actually see somewhere, then you will still need to implement that somehow.

Comment: Yes, that's what they told me when they offered me this javascript, but I don't really understand its meaning. The idea is that it refreshes automatically

Answer (score 1):

To add a secondary add to cart button (with a quantity of 10) for specific products on WooCommerce archives, use the following:

```php
// Add an "Add 10 to Cart" button on archives for specific products
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'display_second_add_to_cart_10', 15);
function display_second_add_to_cart_10() {
    global $product;

    if ( $product ) {
        $targeted_ids = array(3092, 422); // Array of allowed products Ids
        
        if ( ! in_array($product->get_id(), $targeted_ids) ) return;

        if ( $product->supports( 'ajax_add_to_cart' ) && $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() ) {
            woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart( ['quantity' => 10] );
        }
    }
}

// Change add to cart text to "Add 10 to Cart"
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'filter_loop_add_to_cart_10_text', 10, 3 );
function filter_loop_add_to_cart_10_text( $button, $product, $args  ) {
    if ( $args['quantity'] == 10 ) {
        $button_text    = __("Add 10 to Cart", "woocommerce"); // Text replacement
        $args['class'] .= 'button_10 alt'; // Custom classes

        $button = sprintf(
            '<a href="%s" data-quantity="%s" class="%s" %s>%s</a>',
            esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
            esc_attr( isset( $args['quantity'] ) ? $args['quantity'] : 1 ),
            esc_attr( isset( $args['class'] ) ? $args['class'] : 'button' ),
            isset( $args['attributes'] ) ? wc_implode_html_attributes( $args['attributes'] ) : '',
            esc_html( $button_text )
        );
    }
    return $button;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

[image]

Related: [How does woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link filter hook work in depth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56177919/how-does-woocommerce-loop-add-to-cart-link-filter-hook-work-in-depth/56179393#56179393)

Comment: Oups! sorry, my fault… I have updated the code.

Comment: My provided code to your answer is tested and works perfectly... But it doesn't seem to work for you, as you may have made too many other customizations that are interfering with my answer code.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. The only code I have on the site regarding the buttons is to put the add more products buttons. You can see it at the [Paiza link](https://paiza.io/projects/e/y9E1B8xG1aXaR-YlG2467Q?theme=twilight). Maybe you can see if the problem is found in that code, I don't understand if it is

Comment: Thanks for your support. I don't have social networks. I don't use a chat app, I have problems and I don't like having contact. I really appreciate what you are trying to do, you really are a good person. I'll see if I can get it with the code you provided. I don't understand if it works for you, because for you it only adds 1 product instead of 10. I have a fragment to change the button text..  `add_filter('woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_archive_custom_cart_button_text');
function woo_archive_custom_cart_button_text()
{  return __('COMPRAR', 'woocommerce');}`

Comment: Hello @LoicElAzteca , I'm very sorry to bother you. We have disabled all the plugins and removed the extra code created by my partner but it doesn't work for me...
Finally we think it might be something related to our Flatsome theme. We're writing to see if they have anything WooCommerce-related that could interfere.

Comment: I got the creators of Flatsome to listen to me. I have been offered this code snippet that works. I would like to know your opinion since I see that you have a lot of experience:

Comment: `add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', function() {
  global $product;
  $product_id = $product->get_id();

  if ( $product_id == 3092 || $product_id == 422 ) {
      if ( $product->supports( 'ajax_add_to_cart' ) && $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() ) {
          echo '<a href="?add-to-cart=' . $product_id . '&quantity=10" class="primary is-small mb-0 button ajax_add_to_cart add_to_cart_button is-outline">Añade 10 unidades</a>';
      }
  }
}, 10);`